# How can I expand this power expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I start with $ b \cdot \lg(n) + c $ where $\lg$ is $ \log_2 $, and then make it an exponent of base 2, I get:

$  2^{b \cdot \lg(n) + c} $

How can I simplify this? I've figured the first step out:

$ 2^{b \cdot \lg(n)} \cdot 2^c$

How can I further expand the first term?

Comment: $$b\log_2n=\log_2 n^b\implies 2^{b\log_2n}=n^b\;\ldots$$

Comment: The definition of $\lg n$ is $$2^{\lg n} = n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$
 2^{b \cdot \lg(n)} \cdot 2^c.$$

First use the law that says $a^{pq} = \left(a^p\right)^q$ to transform $2^{b \cdot \lg(n)}$ to $\left(2^{\lg n}\right)^{b}$.

The definition of $\lg n$ is that $$2^{\lg n} = n,$$ so $$\left(2^{\lg n}\right)^{b} = n^b.$$

So your original expression, $2^{b \cdot \lg(n)} \cdot 2^c$, is equal to $n^b\cdot 2^c$.

You may or may not consider this an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{b\log_2n+c}=2^{b\log_2n}\cdot2^c=(2^{\log_2n})^b\cdot2^c$$

Now use $\displaystyle a^{\log_am}=m$ where $\log_am$ remains defined

Comment: Still stuck unfortunately. I do not understand the $ \displaystyle a^{\log_am}=m $ part.